# Wikimapia Place.Search Doesn't Work

Tags: search, wikimapia

I want to use wikimapia place.search api function but im getting empty result always even renew mykey (i don't think my key causing this problem).

```
http://api.wikimapia.org/?function=place.search&key=blabla&q=cafe&lat=39.9728&lon=32.724&format=json&language=en&page=1&count=100&category=&categories_or=&categories_and=&distance=10000
```

what im doing wrong. i've also created new key but doesnt work. result always empty.

Can you help me please?